# Firebase Firestore Query Using NSPredicate in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nspredicate

According to the Firestore documentation, it is possible to create a Query using .filter(using: NSPredicate). I tried this using the following code (Swift 5, iOS 12.4, Xcode 11):

```
    let predCondition = "title BEGINSWITH %@"
    let searchKeyText = "Uxbridge"
    let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format:predCondition, searchKeyText.lowercased())
    let mapsRef = dbFS.collection("mapDetails")
    let query = mapsRef.filter(using:myPredicate)
    query.getDocuments()
    { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let snap = querySnapshot, snap.isEmpty
        {
            print("Document not found")
        }
        else
        {
            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            }
            else
            {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents
                {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This compiled but resulted in an exception at run time:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid query. Operator type 8 is not supported.'

It seems that the type of predicate "title BEGINSWITH %@" is not supported.  Does anyone know what types are available? I could not see anything in the documentation but if there is something I missed, I would appreciate it if someone would direct me to it.  Also is there any possibility that BEGINSWITH, etc. may be supported in the near future? Thx. RB